# E-Business Suite Security ORA_BIPS_LBINFO attribute

Tags: security, cookies, suite

in Oracle E-Business Suite Security there is a cookie with the attribute `ORA_BIPS_LBINFO`. Does anyone knows what's the meaning of this?

thank you!